# Ceylon fat-jar with non-default run function

Tags: ceylon

I have a simple [http server](https://herd.ceylon-lang.org/modules/ceylon.http.server/1.3.3) in a folder named POSTtoFile. It has one module (`server`) with one package (`server`) with a file `runServer.ceylon` with a function `runServer` which is the main method. Building a fat jar like this:

```
ceylon fat-jar server/1.0.0 --run=server::runServer
```

and running the jar like this:

```
java server-1.0.0.jar
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class server-1.0.0.jar
```

buiding the fat jar like this:

```
ceylon fat-jar server/1.0.0 --run=runServer
```

gives the same outcome.

I followed [this guide](https://ceylon-lang.org/blog/2016/06/29/ceylon-fat-jars/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a jar file is done with `java -jar server-1.0.0.jar`.
If you omit the `-jar` parameter, it is trying to load a class named `server-1.0.0.jar` (which is not a valid class name, at least in Java, not sure about the JVM).